# Can I change the LookAndFeel of a Java Webstart Program

Tags: java, html, user-interface

((I'm an industrial construction engineer (recently graduated) and at the place I recently started working we use a Java Program, developed by an external company, to calculate the price of industrial buildings including everything.))

I have a html link on my desktop and it starts a Java Applet/ Web Start (?), I have to click Run, and after that a new (native windows) window pops up with the program running in it.

Everything looks super old, ugly skin, bad fonts, I hate it. In old manuals (2013) the program (on screenshots) has a native windows look and feel.
However, the most recent versions look SHIT.

Question: Do I have to contact the writer of the code @ the external company to change the look and feel back to native OS?

Or is there someway for me to crack into the code and force a parameter or something?

I'm kinda noob at Java but I'm a quick learner, shoot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the nimbus look-and-feel. You need at least JDK 6 for nimbus. There are more ways how to do it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/nimbus.html

As you can see on this link, you can do it programmatically inside the java program.

BUT there are 2 other ways how you can do it by configuration:

1.

> Permanently set the default look and feel to Nimbus by adding the
>   following line to the JAVA_HOME/lib/swing.properties file:
>
> swing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel 
>   If the swing.properties file does not yet exist, you need to create it.

2.

> Specify Nimbus as the default look and feel for a particular
>   application at the command line, as follows: 
>   java -Dswing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel MyApp

In the 2nd case the java command line (in case of JWS) is coming from the .jnlp xml descriptor which is part of the deployed JWS application jar file.

There is a resources section in the .jnlp which looks something like this:

```
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" java-vm-args="-esa -Xnoclassgc -Xms32m"/>
    ...
  </resources>
```

which you should extend with the nimbus property values like this:

```
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" java-vm-args="-esa -Xnoclassgc -Xms32m"/>
    <property name="swing.laf" value="com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel" />
    <property name="swing.defaultlaf" value="com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel" />
    ...
  </resources>
```

to get the intended java command line created.

Answer (score -1):

As almost everything in the programming...

It depends. There's a way to get java code from the jar file (The term java developers use is "decompile"), but there's a process called "obfuscation" wich prevents this sometimes. There's a high chance, that the the program you use contains obfuscated code. If the code is obfuscated then you get an uncompilable code, and you would need to pretty much rewrite the whole codebase.

This is not the only problem, deobfuscating code is not 100% illegal, but you are permitted, to share the code or the recompiled program. Keep this in mind, if you choose this path.

To decompile a jar file, you can use [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/). Then you need to save the java files you get to a directory. You can open these with a normal text editor, but I'd advise you to get a java IDE, such as [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/).

After this, it's pretty easy to change, how a GUI looks. You can check java GUI tutorials about this.

Comment: Thank you I will check this out!
And what if the jar file is on an external server, hardly reachable

Comment: @Jelle WebStart programs are on your computer, but they check for updates automatically, sadly, you can't do it this way then.